# memory sharing between app domains

Tags: .net, appdomain

For each process a separate memory is allocated. In .net the process can contain multiple app domains. How the memory is allocated for each app domain? Do they share the common memory of the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not allowed to access the same memory and share objects in this memory space, objects should be marshalled when you pass them from one app domain to another one:

[Application Domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx#benefits)

> Code running in one application cannot directly access code or
>   resources from another application. The common language runtime
>   enforces this isolation by preventing direct calls between objects in
>   different application domains. Objects that pass between domains are
>   either copied or accessed by proxy. If the object is copied, the call
>   to the object is local. That is, both the caller and the object being
>   referenced are in the same application domain. If the object is
>   accessed through a proxy, the call to the object is remote. In this
>   case, the caller and the object being referenced are in different
>   application domains. **Cross-domain calls use the same remote call
>   infrastructure as calls between two processes or between two machines.**
>   As such, the metadata for the object being referenced must be
>   available to both application domains to allow the method call to be
>   JIT-compiled properly. If the calling domain does not have access to
>   the metadata for the object being called, the compilation might fail
>   with an exception of type System.IO.FileNotFound

Comment: on 32 bit machine, if the available ram is 4GB, the CLR allocates 1.5 GB to 2GB for an application. So how this memory is shared. Does each app domain will get 2GB?